# System of differential equation with delay

Tags: differential-equations

I try to solve this differential  system with delay:

```
DSolve[x'[t] == -0.12  x[t]  - 
   0.8 *  1.77   x[t] /(1 + x[t]^4)
      E^(-0.1  * 
     2.8    ) (1.6 * 1.77  1/(1 + x[t - 2.8]^4) +  0.01) x[
     t - 2.8] - (0.51/61)^-0.001  p[t]/(
    p[t] + 1) ((2.5*10^4 - 2.5*10^4 * 0.4 * 0.01)/(2.5*10^4)^0.99) x[
     t]^0.99, d'[t] == - 0.61  d[t] + 200 , 
 p'[t] == -0.0412 p[t] + 0.61 d[t], {x[t], d[t], p[t]}, t]
```

In the render I wasn't able to understand the error message.

Is there any charitable sool to help me out.

Comment: You need your three equations inside { and }. You have x'[t], y'[t] and p'[t] but are solving for x[t], d[t] and p[t]. There is still at least one more error I can't see at the moment.

Comment: DSolve might not recognize that  x[t - 2.8] is just the time delay of x[t]. By the way, can DSolve solve time delay differential equation?

Comment: @Bill Excuse me. p[t] instead y[t], I give the correction.

Comment: @Harry In mathematica 10 it is possible to sove an EDO with delay.

Comment: @Zbigniew: First, you will have to enclose the equations in curly brackets, then you might need to specify the historic behavior, e.g. like `x[t/;t<=0]==(*whatever*)`, and finally, you need to specify the range of `t`, e.g. `{t,0,2}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the corrections suggested by Jinxed (with `whatever` set to `1`) plus the additional correction of specifying the range of `t` (required for a delay differential equation), the code becomes

```
DSolve[{x'[t] == -0.12 x[t] - 0.8*1.77 x[t]/(1 + x[t]^4) E^(-0.1*2.8) (1.6*1.77 1/(1 + 
  x[t - 2.8]^4) + 0.01) x[t - 2.8] - (0.51/61)^-0.001 p[t]/(p[t] + 1) 
  ((2.5*10^4 - 2.5*10^4*0.4*0.01)/(2.5*10^4)^0.99) x[t]^0.99,
  d'[t] == -0.61 d[t] + 200, 
  p'[t] == -0.0412 p[t] + 0.61 d[t], 
  x[t /; t <= 0] == 1}, {x[t], d[t], p[t]}, ,{t, 0, 10}]
```

Since `DSolve` runs "forever", trying to solve this problem, I simplified the code by solving for `d` and `p`, which are independent of `x`.

```
ans1 = First@DSolve[{d'[t] == -0.61 d[t] + 200, p'[t] == -0.0412 p[t] + 0.61 d[t]}, {d[t],p[t]}, t]
(* {d[t] -> 327.869 + 1. E^(-0.61 t) C[1], 
    p[t] -> 1. E^(-0.0412 t) (5205.99 E^(0.0412 t) - 351.617 E^(0.61 t)) + 
    351.617 E^(-0.0412 t) (-1. E^(0.0412 t) + 1. E^(0.61 t)) + 
    1.07243 E^(-0.6512 t) (-1. E^(0.0412 t) + 1. E^(0.61 t)) C[1] + 1. E^(-0.0412 t) C[2]} *)
```

These then are substituted into the remaining differential equation

```
eq = Simplify[x'[t] == -0.12 x[t] - 0.8*1.77 x[t]/(1 + x[t]^4) E^(-0.1*2.8)
  (1.6*1.77 1/(1 + x[t - 2.8]^4) + 0.01) x[t - 2.8] - (0.51/61)^-0.001 p[t]/(p[t] + 1) 
  ((2.5*10^4 - 2.5*10^4*0.4*0.01)/(2.5*10^4)^0.99) x[t]^0.99 /. ans1]
```

The resulting expression, which is rather long to be displayed here, when inserted into `DSolve`

```
DSolve[{%, x[t /; t <= 0] == 1}, x[t], t]
```

still runs "forever", perhaps due to the `x[t]^0.99` term.

This being the case, I used `NDSolveValue`.  Doing so requires that the constants `C[1]` and `C[2]` be specified, and I chose `0`.  (Alternatively, one could use `ParametricNDSolveValue` with the two constants as parameters.)

```
Simplify[eq/.{C[1] -> 0, C[2] -> 0}]
sol = NDSolveValue[{%, x[t /; t <= 0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 10}]
LogPlot[sol[t], {t, 0, 10}, AxesLabel -> {t, x}, PlotRange -> {10^-8, 1}]
```

[image]